# Missing mailing list subscription check box in Chrome, and Edge

Tags: wordpress, mailing

The mailing list subscription check box missing form subscription page when I open the page in Chrome or Edge under win10, same with android tablet and mobile phone Chrome browser.
Works correctly in Firefox 47.0

Civi 4.7.9 under WordPress 4.5.3. with Hungarian settings. [image: see in sreenshot taken in Chrome]

Consequently no one can subcribe to the mailing list, and get "Please select one or more mailing lists." error message!

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a JavaScript issue.  Please see the [Javascript Troubleshooting Guide](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850) for CiviCRM.  If that doesn't solve your problem, edit your question to indicate what you've tried and what information you gathered from following the steps in the guide.

You may also want to try one of the default WordPress themes and see if the problem persists.  If you try this, please update the question to indicate what the results were.

Answer (score 1):

I use Ascent template when problems happens.

If I test with the twenty sixteen default template no problems.

I will look around the Javascript.

Thanks for your help.